# How to get mysql data using modal view PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I'm trying to get MySQL value using modal view, for please check this URL http://demo.namastehost.com/account/update.php?id=13

I want to get value where id=id, but I didn't get any clue from where I can assign id=id in modal view.
Please suggest.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">update Details</button>
<!-- Modal-->
<div id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade text-left">
  <div role="document" class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 id="exampleModalLabel" class="modal-title">Truck Details</h5>
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" class="close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>

        <head>

          <title>Update Record</title>


          <div>
            <form name="form" method="post" action="">
              <input type="hidden" name="new" value="1" />
              <input name="id" type="hidden" value="db value should be here!" />
              <p><input id="weight" type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Enter Weight" required value="db value should be here!" /></p>
              <p><input id="c_rate" type="text" name="c_rate" placeholder="Enter Rate" required value="db value should be here!" /></p>
              <p><input readonly id="c_total" type="text" name="c_total" placeholder="Enter Total" required value="db value should be here!" /></p>
              <p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Update" /></p>
            </form>
            <?php } ?>
          </div>
```

Comment: your HTML is all wrong, your javascript and modal code should be in the html head/body, not before the doctype declaration!

Answer (score 0):

as you asking "how to get id=id", short answer is you should use the `$_GET` (query) param.

(the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

for example:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

and you can use the `$id` however you want

Comment: Except that the OP seems to be using POST in the forms attributes `<form name="form" method="post" action=""> `